# Print several lines between patterns (first pattern not unique)

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

Need help with sed/awk/grep/whatever could solve my task.
I have a large file and I need to extract multiple sequential lines from it.

I have start pattern: `<DN>`

and end pattern: `</GR>`

and several lines in between, like this:

```
<DN>234</DN>
<DD>sdfsd</DD>
<BR>456456</BR>
<COL>6575675 sdfsd</COL>

<RAC>456464</RAC>
<GR>sdfsdfsFFFDd</GR>
```

I've tried this:

```
sed -n '/\<DN\>/,/\<\/GR\>/p'
```

and several other ones (using awk and sed).
It works okay, but the problem is that the source file may contain lines starting with `<DN>` and without `</GR>` in the end of the bunch of lines, and then starts a part with another  and normal  in the end:

```
<DN>234</DN> - unneded DN
<AB>sdfsd</AB>
<DC>456456</DC>
<EF>6575675 sdfsd</EF>
....really large piece of unwanted text here....

<DN>234</DN>
<DD>sdfsd</DD>
<BR>456456</BR>
<COL>6575675 sdfsd</COL>

<RAC>456464</RAC>
<GR>sdfsdfsFFFDd</GR>
<RAC>456464</RAC>
<GR>sdfsdfsFFFDd</GR>
```

How can I extract only needed lines and ignore garbage pieces of log, containing `<DN>` without ending `</GR>`?

And next, I need to convert a multiline pieces from `<DN>` to `</GR>` to a file with single lines, starting with `<DN>` and ending with `</GR>`. 
Any help would be appreciated. I'm stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `pcregrep` tool for this.

```
$ pcregrep -o -M '(?s)(?<=^|\s)<DN>(?:(?!<DN>).)*?</GR>(?=\n|$)' file
<DN>234</DN>
<DD>sdfsd</DD>
<BR>456456</BR>
<COL>6575675 sdfsd</COL>

<RAC>456464</RAC>
<GR>sdfsdfsFFFDd</GR>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Unfortunately your suggestion didn't work on actual file. Maybe that's because system treats it as a binary file, I have to add -a option to grep command to make it work. But there is no such option for pcregrep.

Comment: could you post the exact file contents in pastebin or in your question?

Comment: it's too large, i'm afraid. Several hundred megabytes of file contains only a few valuable lines of data which I need to extract. And it's from production system and contains client data.

Comment: This one worked for me in the end:    pcregrep --buffer-size=100000000 -o -M '(?s)(?<=^|\s)<DN>(?:(?!<DN>).)*?</GR>'

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/<DN>/{h;b};x;/./G;x;/<\/GR/{x;/./p;z;x}' file
```

Use the hold space to store lines between `<DN>` and `</GR>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
# Lines that start with '<DN>' start our matching.
/^<DN>/ {
    # If we saw a start without a matching end throw everything we've saved away.
    if (dn) {
        d=""
    }
    # Mark being in a '<DN>' element.
    dn=1
    # Save the current line.
    d=$0
    next
}

# Lines that end with '</GR>$' end our matching (but only if we are currently in a match).
dn && /<\/GR>$/ {
    # We aren't in a <DN> element anymore.
    dn=0
    # Print out the lines we've saved and the current line.
    printf "%s%s%s\n", d, OFS, $0
    # Reset our saved contents.
    d=""
    next
}

# If we are in a <DN> element and have saved contents append the current line to the contents (separated by OFS).
dn && d {
    d=d OFS $0
}
' file
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, that's really great. I don't even know how to use this. Should I copy this to a script? If I do so nothing happens. System runs it for several seconds and then prints nothing. But file do contain matching data if i check it manually or with grep -a.

Comment: Does the file have DOS line endings? Does `grep '</GR>$'` find matching lines? Does 'grep '^<DN>'`?

Comment: Actually file does not have line endings (at least notepad++ doesn't show any CRLF or anything like this), it's kinda binary, but contains large pieces of text, mixed with binary data.     grep -a '^<DN>' 20140905.log     finds many matches.      grep '</GR>$' 20140905.log     - doesn't

Comment: @IvanBondarets If the file isn't a "text file" then using text tools on it is less than reliable. That being said you could try using `/<\/GR>/` in the script instead (dropping `$`) if those aren't the end of the line. Assuming that still matches what you want correctly it might work out.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
  /^<DN>/ { n = 1 }

  n { lines[n++] = $0 }

  n && /<\/GR>$/ {
    for (i=1; i<n; i++) printf "%s", lines[i]
    print ""
    n = 0
  }
' file
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I need an advice how to use it :) If I copy it into a script and change "file" to my actual file name - nothing happens. System runs it for several seconds and prints nothing.

Comment: For both awk solutions, you can copy paste the code onto your command line and only change the `file` input as appropriate to `myFileInput.txt` (or similar). (I would copy into notepad and fix the file name, the select/copy/paste onto the command line). The better solution is to save either of these into files, and call with `awk -f solutionN.awk myInputFile.txt`There are several other solutions, but they wont' fit here;-) Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

with bash:

```
fun () 
{ 
    local line output;
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        if [[ $line =~ ^'<DN>' ]]; then
            output=$line;
        else
            if [[ -n $output ]]; then
                output=$output$'\n'$line;
                if [[ $line =~ '</GR>'$ ]]; then
                    echo "$output";
                    output=;
                fi;
            fi;
        fi;
    done
}

fun <file
```